# Woo Stripe No such source: 'src_1HSDYbGnTdOaP0tZcjziW81K' Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm currently working with stripe woocommerce for my wordpress project, when I proceed a checkout using saved cards it shown me an error like this

No such source: 'src_1HSDYbGnTdOaP0tZcjziW81K'

Adding new cards for checkout is fine, but using saved cards is not working at all and I don't know how to fix this. Please help me thank you

I have the same situation with this query:
[Woocommerce Stripe No such source: 'src_1HSDYbGnTdOaP0tZcjziW81K' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022184/woocommerce-stripe-no-such-source-src-1hsdybgntdoap0tzcjziw81k-error)

sadly i dont see the answer on this link

Comment: Have you checked here? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-such-source-error-on-testing-stripe/

Comment: Usually this is because you're using the wrong API key (wrong account, live vs test mode). If you're sure this is the correct key, it could be that you're trying to access a source that has already been consumed/isn't reusable. Was the source ever attached to a customer?

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem today. I have this problem after switch the API to different Stripe account.
So, I use a different CCV 3 digits number compare to previous saved CC details, and the problem is gone. Manage to complete the checkout.
Alternatively, you can clear saved CC details from your Payment Method under the MyAccount page.

Note: I use Stripe for WooCommerce

Answer (score 0):

I was also using Stripe for WooCommerce and had changed the API from my developer test stripe account to the customers test stripe account. Prior to switching API accounts, I had previously submitted a test payment via Stripe and saved the card, but after switching API accounts, this error occurred when I tried to use the "saved" card details.

Using "user2601660" suggestion above, I chose to enter a new test card with a different expiry date and CCV number, and it went through just fine.